# When should I trigger an Android Alert Dialog?

Tags: android

From time to time I find myself wanting to create and show AlertDialog immediately after an Activity starts.  In the past I've done:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ...
    builder.create.show(); 
    ...
}
```

This seems bad because the activity hasn't actually been created yet.  And from time to time I see the screen "dim" as though the AlertDialog is supposed to be on the screen, but it doesn't actually appear.

More recently I've been using a Handler/Runnable to delay the launch of the AlertDialog by a few milliseconds.  That seems fairly arbitrary too.

What is the best practice for presenting an AlertDialog immediately after an Activity initializes?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking the activity has been created but it's content hasn't been.

A lot of people put too much into the `onCreate()` method.

The first method you can override where the views exist is `onContentChanged()`, so this is a good place to do things to views, like set a value.

You can as previously stated use `onStart()` or possibly even `onResume` depending on your requirements.

For further information please see the [Android Activity LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: One issue with using the onStart method is that it fires each time the Activity becomes visible.  Same goes for onResume, although it may actually be worse because onResume will fire after the dialog is dismissed.  onContentChanged() I'll look in to.

Comment: .. yes that's why I said depending on your requirements.  I suspect that the onStart() feature is actually a bug in android ... it makes no sense for an activity to fire this when it comes to the fore.  Android seems only to work properly for google and nobody else.

Comment: a bit of a hack but you could set a flag in onRestart() and check for its value in onStart() that was you would know whether it was correct to show the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Show the dialog in `onStart` or `onWindowFocusChanged`